# How to benchmark with Method.invoke in Java

Tags: java, benchmarking

While I was programming a micro-benchmark service for an SQL wrapper I'm programming, I decided to use a method of bench-marking that involved annotating benchmark methods. The problem is that Method.invoke() has a slight overhead (depending on your system). While this would be acceptable if I was bench-marking *very* long tasks, these tests last only about half a second on average, and every microsecond can really change how a benchmark result looks.

Is there any way to work around this overhead, or is there a way to time the processing internally (eg. via a java method)?

Comment: So you want to benchmark a method that is usually invoked via reflection but you want to avoid the overhead of reflection during the benchmark? Why not just benchmark the target method directly?

Comment: Because, to make it easier on me, I have each test method annotated in a class, so I don't have to go through the process of making a class that extends an interface over and over for every test I want to do, but maybe that might be the only way to do it.

Comment: Have you looked into using the [Java Microbenchmark Harness (JMH)](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) tool (here's [a small tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html))?

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted; I want to be able to include the benchmarking independent of other dependencies or in a separate jar. While I'm sure that doing it this way is much better for myself and my application, I'd rather do it independently. Maybe peaking at the source code might point me in the right direction.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand. For instance, if you use the _de facto_ Gradle plugin for JMH it creates a separate source set for the JMH benchmark classes. Maven might do something similar (never used JMH with Maven). Of course, you can use JMH independently of any build tools, but the point is the benchmark test sources are typically separated from production sources (same as with unit tests).

Comment: Tests need to be able to be done on production as well, in my case, with an argument (--dbTest).

Comment: The benchmark code would have access to the production code. The situation is similar to unit tests. Typically unit test sources are separated out from production sources but depend on the production sources (but production sources _don't_ depend on test sources). Unless you're saying you want to be able to run the tests _while the application is deployed_?

Comment: Yes. Essentially, that's what I want to do. Aside from a couple other things, that is.